# Laravel store multiple value in different row

Tags: laravel

would you like to help me? I want to input multiple value and store in database with different row. For example :

In input form,

```
|project_id    milestone_id|
|    1          1,2,3      |
|    2           2,4       |
```

My expected result in database

```
|project_id    milestone_id|
|    1              1      |
|    1              2      |
|    1              3      |
|    2              2      |
|    2              4      |
```

This is my view (tasktable\projectmiles.blade.php)

```
<form action="{{route('project-miles.store')}}" method="post">
  <label for="project" class="control-label mb-1">Project</label>
  <div class="input-group col-lg-12">
    <select name="project_id" id="project_id" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      @foreach ($projects as $item)
        <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->value}} - {{$item->description}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  <label for="milestone" class="control-label mb-1">Milestone</label>
  <div class="input-group col-lg-12">
    <select multiple="multiple" name="milestone_id" id="milestone_id" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      @foreach ($milestones as $item)
        <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->value}} - {{$item->description}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block"></button>
</form>
```

This is my controller (ProjectMilestoneController.php) and I take value from 2 model (Milestone and Project)

```
class ProjectMilestoneController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $projects = Project::get();
    $milestones = Milestone::get();
    return view('takstable.projectmiles',['projects'=>$projects, 'milestones'=>$milestones]);   
  }      

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    ProjectMilestone::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('project-miles.index');
  }
}
```

This is my model (ProjectMilestone.php)

```
class ProjectMilestone extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['project_id','milestone_id'];
  public function project()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class,'project_id','id');
  }

  public function milestone()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Milestone::class,'milestone_id','id');
  }
}
```

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Eloquent` way to achieve this is,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    foreach($request->milestone_id as $milestone_id) {

        ProjectMilestone::create([
            'project_id'   => $request->project_id,
            'milestone_id' => $milestone_id
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->route('project-miles.index');
}
```

But this affect the efficiency of the system because if there are n number of milestones selected, there will be n number of queries to the database.

In order to avoid this issue.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $prject_milestone = collect();

    foreach($request->milestone_id as $milestone_id) {

        $project_milestones->push(
            ProjectMilestone::make([
                'project_id'   => $request->project_id,
                'milestone_id' => $miletone_id
            ])
        );
    }

    DB::table('project_milestones')->insert($project_milestones);

    return redirect()->route('project-miles.index');
}
```

this will execute only one query to the database.

**The Choice is yours**

Comment: thank you for your help. I try to use the second code and I got error like this Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp3\htdocs\budgeting\app\Http\Controllers\ProjectMilestoneController.php on line 45 (line 45 is DB::table('project_milestones')->insert($project_milestones))

Comment: Finally I use the first code and it works, thank you very much

Comment: In case you are still interested in the second approach, maybe the Collection objects causing the error. so try this. `DB::table('project_milestones')->insert($project_milestones->toArray()));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make array on view also. ex :

```
<select name="milestone_id[]" id="milestone_id" class="form-control">
```

Refer @tharakaDilshan's answer for controller.